# Can I use a Case Statement to decide which table to update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write some SQl that will choose which table to update depending on the value of a parameter that is passed in

Is something like the below possible ?

```
UPDATE    CASE @param
            WHEN '02' THEN dbo.Employer
            WHEN '03' THEN dbo.Group
            WHEN '04' THEN dbo.Sub_Group
            WHEN '05' THEN dbo.Member
            WHEN '07' THEN dbo.Claim
            WHEN '08' THEN dbo.Contact
        END
        SET Status_PKID = 4
        WHERE Request_PKID = 1
```

I've tried something along this lines but I'm getting syntax errors around the case statement. I'm wondering if this is just a question of me writing the SQL correctly or do I have to rewrite this whole thing in a very different way(possibly using IF statements and individual UPDATEs for each table)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you would need IF statements

```
IF @param = '02'
UPDATE dbo.Employer
SET Status_PKID = 4
WHERE Request_PKID = 1

IF @param = '03'
UPDATE dbo.Group
SET Status_PKID = 4
WHERE Request_PKID = 1

IF @param = '04'
UPDATE dbo.Sub_Group
SET Status_PKID = 4
WHERE Request_PKID = 1

IF @param = '05'
UPDATE dbo.Member
SET Status_PKID = 4
WHERE Request_PKID = 1

IF @param = '07'
UPDATE dbo.Claim
SET Status_PKID = 4
WHERE Request_PKID = 1

IF @param = '08'
UPDATE dbo.Contact
SET Status_PKID = 4
WHERE Request_PKID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

You could use dynamic SQL to achieve something similar.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

select @sql = 'UPDATE ' +   CASE @param
            WHEN '02' THEN 'dbo.Employer'
            WHEN '03' THEN 'dbo.Group'
            ...
        END + ' SET Status_PKID = 4 WHERE Request_PKID = 1'
```

but it's probably a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

Use Dynamic query

```
SET @table = (CASE @param
            WHEN '02' THEN 'dbo.Employer'
            WHEN '03' THEN 'dbo.Group'
            WHEN '04' THEN 'dbo.Sub_Group'
            WHEN '05' THEN 'dbo.Member'
            WHEN '07' THEN 'dbo.Claim'
            WHEN '08' THEN 'dbo.Contact' END)

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE  ' + @Table + ' SET Status_PKID = 4 WHERE Request_PKID = 1'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL =  N'UPDATE  [dbo].'  +  CASE @param
                                     WHEN '02' THEN QUOTENAME(Employer)
                                     WHEN '03' THEN QUOTENAME(Group)
                                     WHEN '04' THEN QUOTENAME(Sub_Group)
                                     WHEN '05' THEN QUOTENAME(Member)
                                     WHEN '07' THEN QUOTENAME(Claim)
                                     WHEN '08' THEN QUOTENAME(Contact)
                                  END
        +  N'  SET Status_PKID = 4
           WHERE Request_PKID = 1 '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```